# How to define global hotkeys for rich:tree element in RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a problem.
I am using rich:tree element for representing menu in my application.
This tree is always present on the page.
What I would like to do is to define global hotkeys like : CTRL+UP, CTRL+DOWN with which user could automatically go from current menu item to another item.
Hope you understand what I mean.

Now, defining hotkeys is no problem.
I use rich:hotKey.
But what to put in their handler?

Anyone got some experience with this problem?
Guide in the right direction, some help, anything would do.
I'm kind of stuck right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

RichFaces Showcase is not enough?Working with HotKeys is described [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=hotKey) and this tutorials leads to [ComponentControl](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_componentControl.html) which offers a lot of ways how to react on some key event.

Comment: Thank you for your tip about rich:componentControl.
I've never used it before.
It could prove very useful in the future.

But the problem is that rich:tree doesn't have any function defined in it's JavaScript API, so I don't have anything to call on event.

Any other idea?

Comment: Then I am out of ideas. Maybe you will have to write your own JavaScript(JQuery) function.